# Oracle Imp utility issue

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

My application failed to import dump file in to Oracle(11 G) DB which was working till now.

The java code executes 'imp.exe' during the execution as follows,

```
   String impLoc= orDir+"/bin/imp.exe"
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(impLoc + " SK/pwd@orcl  file=mydump.dmp full = y");
```

I could see the user SK is created but with out any tables/data.

The pain points are

- I am not able to reproduce the issue
- No log files is enabled

This code is being executed successfully from last one year (failed once or twice before this, and we ignored :( )
And very unfortunately I did not enabled log attribute and now I am very much clue less what had happened.

I searched most of the log/trace files under oracle home, but could find any thing useful.

It would much appreciated if any body could help me to locate any relevent log file (related to imp utility) to see what had gone wrong.

Comment: if a log is what you need just add `log=mylog.log` to the `imp`  command and rerun.

Comment: Yes I had tried ,but problem is I am not able to replicate the behavior, so I was looking for any system logs/events generated during the import

Comment: so it's not an oracle issue.

Comment: the errors are returned to either standard i/o or the log file. No other log files in the general case. If oracle hits an internal error a foreground trace file would be generated.

Comment: can't you run this yourself on the command line outside of java. Imp shouldn't create the user the user should already be in place imp will add the database objects and data. If you just run imp by itself and post up the error you get someone should be able to help